# How do I set my views to return a 404 using Global: Null under contextual filters?

Tags: views, 7

Standard Drupal behavior is to pass all arguments through, whether or not they requested. Sometimes this behavior is desired. However, I need to return a 404 for anything but a query string.

Example of the problem
http://drupal.org/project/modules
http://drupal.org/project/modules/google.com <- This should return a 404; 200 given. Duplicate content penalty!

The [views 404 module](http://drupal.org/project/views404) assumes that by default you do not want arguments passed through. However there is no D7 version of the module.

But the project page says that 404s for views can also be accomplished by setting the Global: Null under Arguments.

Obviously in D7 "arguments" are now "contextual filters", but I am unsure as to what settings to add to the Global:null contextual filter to get my desired result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In *Contextual filters* select *Add*; in the dialog box that appears, select *Global: Null*.

[image: screenshot]

Click on *Add and configure contextual filters*.

In the dialog box that appear next, in the fieldset *When the filter value is available or a default is provided*, check *Specify validation criteria*, select *- Basic validation -* for *Validator*, and select *Show "Page not found"* for *Action to take if the filter value does not validate*. In the fieldset *More*, check *Fail basic validation if any argument is given*.

[image: screenshot]

I tested it with an "Articles" view I created, and it works.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

The "Global: Null" argument must be the last one. If you need a user ID, for example, first you add it as argument, and then add the "Global: Null" argument.

I altered the "Article" view to accept a user ID as argument, which is used to filter the list of article nodes. The view still works, as it doesn't accept an extra argument.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This will return 403 not 404 code error. Select "Show "Page not found" option instead

Comment: In a thread on D.O. I see someone suggesting to use arg(1)==NULL; in the php validate code. Is this better or pretty much the same thing?

Comment: @EugeneFidelin I was editing the "master" display, and I was not seeing the _Show "Page not found"_ as option. I corrected my answer.

Comment: @NigelWaters Forget my previous answer. `:)` I was editing the wrong display, and the view was not working as it should. There is no need to use PHP code to validate the argument; see the updated answer.

Comment: I don't have enough points to comment yet - so posting here to say thanks to @kiamlaluno. Works great and something I was banging my head against for a while.

Comment: Thx Kiam, one issue I noticed that this solution does not work if there is a pager, otherwise it is good. For example /myinvalidargument?page=10 still shows content instead of 404.

Comment: There is an issue with Global:null. It is ignored when argument equal = all https://www.drupal.org/node/1951456

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using views out of the box functionality. In every contextual filter setting you can see a check-box "Specify validation criteria" check that to see more settings.

Then, you can select "validator" based on your view conditions. If you would like to custom validate then select php code. Return True or False in php code based on your validation conditions.

Finally select "Action to take" as Display Access denied ! See below screenshot for nid contextual filter.

[image]

Comment: What is the php code that I add?

Comment: I am only using the Global:null contextual filter

Comment: NEVER USE PHP CODE IN VIEWS OR ANY OTHER UI TOOL!!!