# Views gives 200 instead of 404 if incorrect argument and a pager is present

Tags: views, paging, 7

I am using with success the global null variable as described here 
[How do I set my views to return a 404 using Global: Null under contextual filters?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/48093/how-do-i-set-my-views-to-return-a-404-using-global-null-under-contextual-filter)

The solution by Kiam works fine, until a pager is added.

So, 
myviews/mybadarg returns 404, but
myviews/mybadarg?page=2022 returns 200

Any tips why?

I tried enabling and disabling pager but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution: I had to set "Show page not found" in the Global Null argument "When the filter value is not in the URL."