# Meaning and Purpose of Global:NULL in views contextual filters

Tags: views

I have been researching using of multiple parameters in a view used as contextual filters like category/1/10/15/11 etc, if all the parameters are present, it works fine, but what if some parameter isnt there in certain sitautions?how to go about this? What I have seen around is Global Null used here and there , but i just cant get a grasp of it, What is actual purpose of GLOBAL NULL?

Comment: Relevant: [How do I set my views to return a 404 using Global: Null under contextual filters?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/48093/how-do-i-set-my-views-to-return-a-404-using-global-null-under-contextual-filter)

Comment: "what if some parameter isnt there" - computers are stupid. Fast, but they can't think. If one of the parameters isn't there, how can a computer tell which one is missing? NULL is to ignore ones you don't want, but it can't provide a null substitution for the ones missing.